# Rerunning requests in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, methodology, database

When performing a meta-analysis, is it advisable to run database requests more than once (i.e. not only in the initial inclusion phase)? If so, what is the expected added value? If not, how to deal with data that have been published between the screening phase and the analysis itself?

Comment: If the journal specifies a maximum time between database search and publication then you will have to rerun the search unless you are super-quick at writing the paper.